# Fusionar archivos CVS en uno solo

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

Estoy tratando de fusionar archivos csv los cuales tienes la misma estructura, los nombres todos comienzan con 505CO72DS80420220714, 505CO72DS80420220715 y asi va cambiando el ultimo valor segun el dia, el problema que tengo es que la decodificacion de estos archivos debe hacerse con latin1 por que tiene muchos caracteres especiales como (ñ).

cuento con dos codigos para realizar el proceso.

1. leer un solo archivo con decodificacion latin1

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   df1=pd.read_csv("C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\505CO72DS8042022070200.csv",delimiter= 
   (";"),encoding='latin1')

   print(df1)
   ```
2. leer todos los archivos de julio y concatenarlos en un solo dataframe

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   import glob
   import os

   # merging the files
   files_joined = os.path.join('C:\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\xxxxx\\xxxxx', "505CO72DS804202207*.csv")

   list_files = glob.glob(files_joined)

   print("** Merging multiple csv files into a single pandas dataframe **")
   # Merge files by joining all files
   dataframe = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, list_files), ignore_index=True)
   print(dataframe)
   ```

En este segundo dataframe me saca error por lo que no esta decodificando con latin1, he tratado de agregar la instruccion como en el primer codigo pero no me funciona o no he logrado ver en donde se debe agregar, agradeceria si alguien me puede ayudar con esto.

Comment: Map ahorra algunos caracteres de codigo, pero es bastante limitado, lo mejor para eso es usar [comprensión de generador](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/). A la izquierda de la comprensión podrás llamar a pd.read_csv y allí pasarle encoding=...

Answer (score 0):

El problema de `map()` es que lo que reciba como primer parámetro (la función a ejecutar) sólo puede recibir un parámetro, que irá tomando los valores del iterable. Pero tú necesitas pasarle dos parámetros a esa función (el nombre del fichero, y el encoding).

Si quieres seguir usando `map()` lo que puedes hacer es pasarle como primer parámetro una expresión lambda que reciba un solo parámetro (el nombre del fichero a leer) y que internamente llame a `pd.read_csv()` pasándole ese parámetro y cualquier otro adicional.

```
dataframe = pd.concat(map(lambda nombre: pd.read_csv(nombre, encoding="latin1"),
                          list_files), ignore_index=True)
```

Otra opción es en lugar de `map()` utilizar una comprensión de listas. O incluso crear la lista antes de llamar a `pd.concat()`, mediante un bucle "normal" que vaya llamando a `pd.read_csv()` y vaya añadiendo los resultados a una lista.

Answer (score 0):

Te estas recalentando la cabeza para hacerlo en una sola linea.

Ahorrate molestias y usa simplemente un for y se lo pasas a concatenate.

Pero antes recopilo los nombres de los archivos de forma distinta con el modulo os y su metodo listdir

```
### IMPORTAR PAQUETES
import os
import pandas as pd

### ACCEDER A LOS NOMBRES DE LOS ARCHIVOS
direccion_carpeta_archivos = r"aqui va tu dir de carpeta"
lista_nombres_archivos = os.listdir(direccion_carpeta_archivos)

### CREAR DATA FRAME VACIO
        df = pd.DataFrame()    
    
### ABRIR ARCHIVOS Y CONCATENARLOS AL DATAFRAME VACIO
        for archivo in list_files:
               archivo_nuevo = pd.read_csv(archivo), ignore_index = True,delimiter= 
    ";",encoding='latin1')
               df = pd.concat( [archivo_nuevo, df]  )
### SE ACABO
        print(df )
```

**Observaciones**

1. El codigo asume que la carpeta existe
2. El codigo asume que hay archivos en la carpeta
3. El codigo asume la estructura del csv como separados por punto coma
4. No se debe eliminar la r que antecede a la string que contiene la
   dir de la carpeta `r"aqui va tu dir de carpeta"`
5. El codigo fallara si cualquiera de las condiciones anteriores no se
   cumplen